# Failed to find Agent-Class manifest attribute

Tags: java, jvm, manifest, javaagents

whenever I try to attach an agent to the JVM I get this error: `Failed to find Agent-Class manifest attribute from /Users/yanjobs/Downloads/Dumper-master-2/out/artifacts/Dumper_master_2_jar/Dumper-master-2.jar`. But when I try to add this parameter (Agent-Class) to my `MANIFEST.MF` the JVM throws me this nice error: `Exception in thread "Attach Listener" Agent failed to start!` and IntelliJ says Invalid agent class (screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpZzN.png)). So... What should I do?
I posted the source [here](https://github.com/Yan-Jobs/soverflow-dumper).

If someone got the time to help me, that would be nice :)

- Yan

Comment: For dynamic attach, your class needs an `agentmain`, not a `premain`. It can have both, through. See the section [Starting an Agent After VM Startup](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) from the `java.lang.instrument` description.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I know that but when I attached it on my manifest it throws me this error: Exception in thread "Attach Listener" Agent failed to start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added this to your manifest:

```
Premain-Class: me.accessmodifier364.dumper.Dumper
Agent-Class: me.accessmodifier364.dumper.Dumper
```

But you forgot to add this to your agent:

```java
public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
    System.out.println("Hot-attaching Dumper...");
    premain(agentArgs, inst);
}
```

How about reading a full tutorial? You might start with [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/java-instrumentation), based on Javassist. But instead of Javassist, you may also use whichever tool you prefer, such as Byte Buddy, ASM, BCEL. The basic code structure (manifest, agent main class, transformer) is the same  in all cases.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked perfectly I’ll look into the guides you provided, thanks !